# GWT map marker callout displayed blank when page first loaded

Tags: java, gwt, google-maps-api-3

I am new to `gwt` and I have a page with a `gwt map` widget and a marker location. When the page is first loaded, the marker callout is displayed with just an X indicating an error.

[image]

When I close the callout and reopen it, the proper data is displayed.

[image]

Here is the gwt code:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(39.565537, -79.426603);


// Init the map options
final MapOptions options = new MapOptions();
// Zoom level. Required
options.setZoom(12);
options.setCenter(location);
// Map type. Required.
options.setMapTypeId(new MapTypeId().getRoadmap());

// Enable maps drag feature. Disabled by default.
options.setDraggable(true);
// Enable and add default navigation control. Disabled by default.
options.setNavigationControl(true);
// Enable and add map type control. Disabled by default.
options.setMapTypeControl(true);

// Create map with options & set as control
final MapWidget retval = new MapWidget(options);

marker.setPosition(location);
marker.setMap(retval.getMap());

String html = "<br />Y Device location at " + loc.updateTime;
if (loc.dmTime != null) {
    html += "<br />Y Received at " + loc.dmTime;
}

infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.setPosition(location);

infoWindow.open(retval.getMap(), marker);

marker.setTitle("Whatever");

Event.addListener(marker, "click", new EventCallback() {
    @Override
    public void callback() {
        infoWindow.open(retval.getMap(), marker);
    }
});

return retval;
```

What do I need to do to get it to display properly when the page is first loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Run `MapWidget.open` when the `GoogleMap` object finishes rendering. To call it when `GoogleMap` object finishes, you need to use `scheduleDeferred` and `addIdleListenerOnce`, , optionally, but preferably, inside `onLoad`:

```
GoogleMap retval;

@Override
protected void onLoad() {
    ...
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {                
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            retval.addIdleListenerOnce(new IdleHandler() {
                @Override
                public void handle() {
                    infoWindow.setContent(html);
                    infoWindow.setPosition(location);
                    infoWindow.open(retval.getMap(), marker);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i am using Google Map API 2.0, I don't have `addIdleListenerOnce` in `Widget`

Comment: The question is tagged as v3, sorry.

Comment: OK.  So i upgraded to v3 but i still don't have `addIdleListenerOnce`

Comment: It seems we're using different libraries. Take a look at this one: https://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/maps/3.8/com/google/maps/gwt/client/GoogleMap.html#addIdleListenerOnce(com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap.IdleHandler)

Comment: thanks.  there seems to be confusion out there regarding versions of Google Maps java API.  i got mine from GitHub (com.github.branflake2267).  Where do I get a jar file that corresponds to the javadoc that you posted

Comment: Link for library download: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list?can=2&q=maps+3.8&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount

Answer (score 0):

`retval` is your `MapWidget` and is returned at the end of your function, so I think you do a `setWidget` later in your code. The `infoWindow.open` is then done before the MapWidget is displayed...
Maybe you can try:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {                
   @Override
   public void execute() {
       infoWindow.open(retval.getMap(), marker);
   }
});
```

to have the InfoWindow displayed after the map is displayed.